# How to increase the font size of a Bootstrap progressbar and center the text?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

How can I easily increase the font size of the text inside a progressbar? And vertically center the text?

```
<div class="progressBarModal">
  <div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="100" aria-valuemin="100" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:100%">
      this should be huge
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Example on Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/Rcdlvue2hC)

Comment: like this .progress-bar {font-size:22px;}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Added a new class which overrides the default font-size in bootstrap

http://www.bootply.com/BmGzxifuk9

Comment: Looks good, but there is one more issue. How can I center the text? Currently your solution puts the text not in the center of the progress-bar.

Comment: use text-align:center

Comment: Provide context for links

Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. (via [How to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer))

Comment: @d4rty - to center use padding..
`.progress-bar {
  padding:15px;
}` http://bootply.com/yd7SkwiWZ8

Answer (score 1):

**use the  following HTML**

```
<div class="progressBarModal">
  <div class="progress" style="height:30px">
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="100" aria-valuemin="100"
    aria-valuemax="100" style="width:100%;    font-size: xx-large;">
      this shoul be huge
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you can set in class as u like

Comment: I know but here i show how to solve the problem not how to manage code

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="progressBarModal">
  <div class="progress" style="height:30px">
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="100" aria-valuemin="100" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:100%;    font-size: xx-large;">
      this shoul be huge
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Check this [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/hUg6DHM17p).

Comment: Same approach like overload1234. In addition how can I vertically center the text ?